# Disapearing Object Instance

Tags: java, web-applications, web-services, jakarta-ee

I've developed an webservice that uses an object instance in order to do part of the required funcionality.

That object is initialized once when I create the webservice class instance throught the use of the constructor.

Sample:

```
public class A {
    private B bInstance;
    public A(){
        bInstance = new B();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly after a few minutes (20 to 30min maybe), my code starts to return a NullPointerException from that object. It is like somehow that object got garbage collected or destroyed.

What can be the cause of this (apart from the possible human mistake)? Maybe I'm missing something specific to web applications

right now I've started to use the object getter that validates for null pointer and rebuilds the object if needed, but that doesn't feel right

Thanks for any tips you might provide

Comment: GC would be horribly broken if it did this. It isn't (with 99% certainty). The problem must be somewhere in your code.

Comment: I know, I've been searching the code for days now, and I haven't found a single line that writes to the variable after being initialized.

Comment: @Katanagashi: Make the variable `final` just to make sure.

Comment: have you got a setter by any chance too which allows other parts of the project to set that instance to null?

Comment: @Jeremy will try that, but first I must change the initialization code in order to do it in "final" variable

Comment: @Liv I did have a setter but did not find any call to it in the project... commenting it out, did not produce any errors.

Comment: adding final to the variable only produced errors at the initialization code that I'm currently changing in order to allow the use of final

Comment: Just rebuilt and deployed the code with the variable defined as final. Since no other errors except for the initialization code had to be corrected I think I can safely assume that there is no other way of this variable being changed.

Comment: @Robin no EJBs, no interfaces only webservices using jax-ws. All this developed using JDeveloper and tested using weblogic.

Comment: Don't know if this is related but the local developer server administrator has a lot of problems with java running out of memory. Server is already using 6GB of Memory using JRockit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible Serialization issue**

It might be possible that your code is being serialized by your application container due to memory issues and that the deserialization process is not correctly creating an instance of B.

Comment: That makes sense, any way of confirming this?

Comment: You could verify that A and B implement Serializable. If they do then write a small example class that uses ObjectOutputStream wrapping FileOutputStream to do the serialization, then bring it back in with ObjectInputStream wrapping FileInputStream and verify that it's worked as expected.